# Is $xy \geq 0$ an equivalence relation?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I have the following question,

Relation on the reals: $x\thicksim y$ means that $xy \geq 0$, and I have to decide whether or not it is an equivalence relation.

First, I know that it is reflexive since I just can take any positive or negative real number and I'll get: $xy \geq 0$.

Deciding whether it is symmetric, I know that if it is, then $x\thicksim y$ and $y \thicksim x $. But if it's not, then $x\thicksim y$ BUT $y \not\thicksim x$.

If I wanted to do a counterexample to show that it is not symmetric, can I just take any number x and -y? (Although I know that will mean that $x \not\thicksim y $ and $y \not\thicksim x$). I have the same problems to show if it's transitive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is reflexive (because $x^2\ge 0$ always) and symmetric (because $xy=yx$). Transitivity is a problem, though. Consider the three numbers $-1$, $0$ and $1$. Which of them are related?

Comment: x~y >= 0, y~z>= 0, but x~z<= 0 then. Thanks so much!

Comment: Method for approaching the problem: compute the equivalence classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show it is (not) symmetric you must show that $x$ ~  $y \Rightarrow y $~$ x $ or not.

If $x $~$ y $ is defined as $xy \geq 0$, does $xy \geq 0 \Rightarrow yx \geq 0$?

For the transitivity, you have to check if $x $~$ y \wedge y $~$ z \Rightarrow x $~$ z  \iff xy \geq 0 \wedge yz \geq 0 \Rightarrow xz \geq 0$

Comment: Yes, it does. I uderstand now, thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 3):

0 ~ -1

0 ~  1

but not -1 ~ 1

It is not an equivalence relation

Answer (score 2):

However, note the relation $x\mathcal R y\stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff}xy>0\;$ *is* an equivalence relation on $\mathbf R^*$, and it has $2$ classes: positive numbers and  negative numbers.

Comment: 0 ~ 0 ? 
I'm sorry...

Comment: No, this would not be reflexive.

Comment: Oops! Sorry. I was thinking in terms of partitions, and didn't check this property. The corresponding equivalence relation is phrased in a simple way only if restricted to $\mathbf R^*$.